# Replace values in Pandas Dataframe with regex if value doesn't contain string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a pretty big dataframe (around 15M rows on 7 columns) and i would like to replace some values that are not having the right shape.

I tried to iterate all over the dataframe but it takes way too long to change the values one by one. 
I also tried to use regex but i couldn't find how to replace if the string doesn't match the regex with pandas.

My dataframe column looks like : 
`1 : L8_P1_Local
 2 : L8
 3 : L8_P1_Local
 4 : L8
 5 : poste2
 6 : poste6
 7 : poste2
 8 : Poste 2
 9 : poste_6`

EDIT: Sometimes the poste2 and poste6 are different like Poste 2 or poste_2 or Poste_2
Does this regex would match everything ? [pP]oste[\s]*[_]*[0-9]

What I'm trying to do is like having the L8 on every row in front of poste2 or poste6 so it would be like `L8_poste6`. I do have the 'L8' string in a variable called `numline`.

Edit: Because the answer was in the accepted's answer comment's I will put it down here.

`text = numligne +'_\\1'
dataframe['row'] = dataframe['row'].str.replace('([pP]oste[ _]*[0-9])', text)`

Comment: Is the `1 :` an artefact for numering the rows or is it in the column value? Said differently is the content of the column `1 : L8_P1_local` or just `L8_P1_local`?

Comment: It is just `L8_P1_Local`. The `1 :` is just the index of the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.Series.str.replace`:

```
s = pd.Series(["1 : L8_P1_Local",
"2 : L8",
"3 : L8_P1_Local",
"4 : L8",
"5 : poste2",
"6 : poste6",
"7 : poste2",])
s.str.replace(' (poste[26])', 'L8_\\1')
```

Output:

```
0    1 : L8_P1_Local
1             2 : L8
2    3 : L8_P1_Local
3             4 : L8
4      5 : L8_poste2
5      6 : L8_poste6
6      7 : L8_poste2
```

There are multiple ways to implement this to the whole dataframe, including (but probably not the fastest):

```
for c in df:
    df[c] = df[c].str.replace(' (poste[26])', 'L8_\\1')
```

Comment: So I should get the Dataframe to a Serie ? Will it be time effective for a big number of rows ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm new to pandas ^^' . So i should be doing something like `dataframe['row'].str.replace(' (poste[26])', 'L8_\\1')` ?

Comment: @Hanggy I've updated my answer for an entire dataset

Comment: For me it is only on one row so your answer was fine. And what about my edit on the regex ? I tried it online with regex101 and it is working.

Comment: @Hanggy in that case, use `s.str.replace(' ([pP]oste[ _]\d)', ' L8_\\1')`

Comment: I have this error : `re.error: invalid group reference 1 at position 4`

Comment: That was because i missed both parentheses

Comment: @Hanggy Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, for you the case of the text doesn't matter. Please check below solution.

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                     'Text':['L8_P1_Local','L8','L8_P1_Local','L8','poste2','poste6','poste2','Poste 2','poste_6']})


    def match_it(s):
        s['Text']=s['Text'].str.lower()
        s['Text']=s['Text'].str.replace(' ','')
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if 'poste' in s.loc[i,'Text']:
                s.loc[i,'Text']='l8'+'_'+s.loc[i,'Text']
        return s    

    match_it(s)
#Output



     ID  Text
    0   1   l8_p1_local
    1   2   l8
    2   3   l8_p1_local
    3   4   l8
    4   5   l8_poste2
    5   6   l8_poste6
    6   7   l8_poste2
    7   8   l8_poste2
    8   9   l8_poste_6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `L8` is it is not there, you can just ask pandas to do that:

So I will assume that you have a DataFrame (say df) with a column (say col) containing your example data :

```
           col
0  L8_P1_Local
1           L8
2  L8_P1_Local
3           L8
4       poste2
5       poste6
6       poste2
```

You could do:

```
df.loc[~df.col.str.match('L8.*'),'col'] = df.loc[
    ~df.col.str.match('L8.*'), 'col'].str.replace('', 'L8_', 1)
```

to get:

```
           col
0  L8_P1_Local
1           L8
2  L8_P1_Local
3           L8
4    L8_poste2
5    L8_poste6
6    L8_poste2
```